# UDP broadcasts - Android app requesting Java server IP Address

Tags: java, eclipse, networking, udp, datagram

I'm trying to get an android app to ping my server, and the server to return its IP Address.

So far, I've got it to communicate with the server and the server to send a packet back, however, I need to send the server IP Address back.

UDPService.java (server)

```
package mySystem.server;


import java.net.*;


public class UDPService implements Runnable {



    public static void main(String args[]) {

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Starting");
        try {
            int port = 1989;

            // Create a socket to listen on the port.
            DatagramSocket dsocket = new DatagramSocket(port);

            // Create a buffer to read datagrams into. If a
            // packet is larger than this buffer, the
            // excess will simply be discarded!
            byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
            byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];

            // Create a packet to receive data into the buffer
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);

            System.out.println("loop start");
            // Now loop forever, waiting to receive packets and printing them.
            while (true) {
                // Wait to receive a datagram

                System.out.println("receive packet");
                dsocket.receive(packet);

                System.out.println("populate sentence");
                String sentence = new String(packet.getData());
                  System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence);

                // Convert the contents to a string, and display them
                System.out.println("send packet");
                dsocket.send(packet);

                // Reset the length of the packet before reusing it.
                System.out.println("setlength");
                packet.setLength(receiveData.length);


            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }

    }
```

Discoverer.java (Phone App)

```
package com.krathsilvercloud.app;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import android.net.DhcpInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.util.Log;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Discoverer extends Thread {
private static final String TAG = "Discovery";
private static final String REMOTE_KEY = "b0xeeRem0tE!";
private static final int DISCOVERY_PORT = 1989;
private static final int TIMEOUT_MS = 5000;
private InetAddress addr;


private static final String mChallenge = "wuffwuff";
private WifiManager mWifi;

interface DiscoveryReceiver {
void addAnnouncedServers(InetAddress[] host, int port[]);
}

Discoverer(WifiManager wifi) {
mWifi = wifi;
try {
    addr = getBroadcastAddress();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Could not get bind address", e);
}
}

public String DiscoverRun() {
try {


    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(DISCOVERY_PORT);
  socket.setBroadcast(true);
  socket.setSoTimeout(TIMEOUT_MS);


  sendDiscoveryRequest(socket);
  return listenForResponses(socket);

} catch (IOException e) {
  Log.e(TAG, "Could not send discovery request", e);
  return null;
}
}


private void sendDiscoveryRequest(DatagramSocket socket) throws IOException {
String data = String.format(mChallenge);
Log.d(TAG, "Sending data " + data);

DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data.getBytes(), data.length(),
    addr, DISCOVERY_PORT);
socket.send(packet);
}


private InetAddress getBroadcastAddress() throws IOException {
DhcpInfo dhcp = mWifi.getDhcpInfo();
if (dhcp == null) {
  Log.d(TAG, "Could not get dhcp info");
  return null;
}

int broadcast = (dhcp.ipAddress & dhcp.netmask) | ~dhcp.netmask;
byte[] quads = new byte[4];
for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
  quads[k] = (byte) ((broadcast >> k * 8) & 0xFF);
return InetAddress.getByAddress(quads);
}


private String listenForResponses(DatagramSocket socket) throws IOException {
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
try {
  while (true) {
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
    socket.receive(packet);
    Log.d(TAG, packet.getAddress().getHostAddress());
    String s = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
    Log.d(TAG, "Received response " + s);


     String IPAddress2 = new String(packet.getAddress().getHostAddress());

    return IPAddress2;

  }
} catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
  Log.d(TAG, "Receive timed out");
  return null;
}
}


private String getSignature(String challenge) {
MessageDigest digest;
byte[] md5sum = null;
try {
  digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
  digest.update(challenge.getBytes());
  digest.update(REMOTE_KEY.getBytes());
  md5sum = digest.digest();
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
for (int k = 0; k < md5sum.length; ++k) {
  String s = Integer.toHexString((int) md5sum[k] & 0xFF);
  if (s.length() == 1)
    hexString.append('0');
  hexString.append(s);
}
return hexString.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
new Discoverer(null).start();
while (true) {
}
}
}
```

search.java (Phone App)

```
Button Submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SearchBtn);
        Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Socket socket;
            PrintWriter out;
            BufferedReader in;
            String Results;

            String SearchStr = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.SearchEntryTxt)).getText().toString().trim();

            String AndroidID = Secure.getString(getBaseContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);

            dis = new Discoverer((WifiManager)getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE));

            IPAddress = dis.DiscoverRun();

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IP Address: >" + IPAddress + "<", 2000);
            toast.show();
```

there's a fair bit of code after this, but it's just an if statement based on what happens if IPAddress is null

Comment: http://www.vogella.de/articles/Eclipse/article.html#classpath_jarjavadoc

Comment: That class is part of the Java distribution, so I'm really not sure how much good having the source will do you. What do you mean there's an error in the class?  Are you getting an exception?  Can you post the code making the call, and the error you are getting?

Comment: Source not found
The source attachment does not contain the source for the file DatagramPacket.class
You can change the source attachment by clicking Change Attached Source below

`IPAddress2 = new String(packet.getAddress().getAddress());`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't mean some non-standard JDK DatagramPacket, [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) should have what you're looking for. Though I must say I'd be surprised if whatever error you havelay in there.